# C# Class declaration to use multiple data type

Tags: c#

I've declared below public class so that I can return multiple data type on my routine:

```
public class dataformat
{
    public int nFlag;
    public String strCommand;
    public String strData;
}
```

Below is the coding I use when I want to return an integer nFlag to b:

```
    public dataformat TxRxProtocol()
    {
        int a;
        dataformat df = new dataformat();

        // coding
        // coding
        // coding
        if (a==0) df.nFlag = 1;
        if (a==1) df.nFlag = 2;

        return df;
     }
```

I have tried:

```
  dataformat b = TxRxProtocol();
  if (b==0) // a condition
  else if (b==1) // a condition
```

But got error stating b is not integer.

How do we write in the TxRxProtocol() routine so that it can return multiple types of value (which include string type) and not just nFlag integer type? Is it that we have to add in df.strCommand = "Something" or df.strData = "Something" in it?

Comment: You declare `b` as an `int`, but `TxRxProtocol` returns `dataformat`. If they are compatible cast it: `b = (int)TxRxProtocol();`

Comment: heh, you're trying to assign dataformat instance to reference which should point to int.

Comment: `b` is `int`, you're trying to assign an instance of `TxRxProtocol` class to it.

Comment: I assume you were were compiling this in Visual studio. I'm sure it highlighted the offending line.

Comment: Then, what is the correct way to return the integer value?

Comment: How do you expect the object to know whether to return the value for strCommand or strData?

Comment: @Coolguy - You need to redesign this. First reword your problem - stating the problem you're trying to solve. For example "I want to write a function that can ...., so that when it return the caller can ...... The things that the function can return are .... and the caller will do .... with them"

Answer (score 3):

You could use an implicit conversion operator:

```
class TxRxProtocol 
{
  public static implicit operator int(TxRxProtocol t)
  {
    return t.nFlag;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would not use this conversion solution, honestly. You are only bound to confuse other people reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 int b = 0;
 dataformat ret = TxRxProtocol();
 b = ret.nFlag;
```

The compiler is right. It's telling you that you're trying to assign a dataformat (returned datum) to the variable b (which is in an int)

you can also make b a dataformat type, which reduces the above to:

```
dataformat b = TxRxProtocol();
```

Of course the use of 'b' depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Actually, the return value from TxRxProtocol() I want it to be any type. How do we write this?

Answer (score 0):

Their types are incompatible, of course it won't work...
Did you mean:

```
 dataformat b = TxRxProtocol();
```

PS: You should capitalize type names.

Comment: Actually, the return value from TxRxProtocol() I want it to be any type. How do we write this?

Answer (score 0):

Variable `b` has to be a type of `dataformat`, so here is a sample:

```
 dataformat b = TxRxProtocol();
```

Comment: Actually, the return value from TxRxProtocol() I want it to be any type. How do we write this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be b = TxRxProtocol().nFalg;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
dataformat b = TxRxProtocol();
if (b==0) // a condition
else if (b==1) // a condition
```

try the below

```
dataformat b = TxRxProtocol();
if (b.nflag==0) // a condition
else if (b.nflag==1) // a condition
```